# SVN adding slashes to quotes

Tags: windows, svn

We have a inhouse subversion server on linux. when I try to check out a project from it, it gives me an error.

Some of the files have ' and ` in the file name. these files were checked in from a Mac, and when I check out the files to a windows machine it adds a slash to the ' & `.

```
my'file.doc becomes my\'file.doc
```

and windows takes this as a folder. is there a way to get around this?

This is the erorr:

[image: SVN error]

This is the file on repo browser:

[image: Repo browser]

Comment: Is it possible that the files checked in from Mac contain non-ASCII characters in their filenames? That might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename the files in the repo browser and remove the `\`.